# Is it possible to compare a element with each element in array except itself in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

Like If an array have 5 elements. So we need to compare a element to all the elements of that array except that element we are comparing with every element. And similarly this rule is applied on comparing each and every elements of the array.
Example- Let's say we have an array of 5 elements-{8,12,15,6,9}. Suppose we are comparing element 3 i.e 15 so I want to know that it is possible to compare 15 with all elements of array except 15 itself? If yes then How?
Well I am newbie in programming and sorry for my bad english too.
It will be great if you provide the code :)
Thank you in advance.

Edit 1- Comparison will be done only if array have multiple unequal values.

Comment: Sure it's possible. What did you try so far? Don't expect that we do all your work.

Comment: Well before m comparing each element with every element. I haven't tried yet doing this? but for surely I will try to figure out this problem.

Comment: What happens if you have multiple elements with the same value?

Comment: Well before comparing this we have another filter to check if all elements are unequal or not if they are all equal then this comparision will be skipped.. Sorry I haven't posted this in question details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the for loop or any other loop add an if statement to execute the rest of your problem only if both values do not match.

```
int arr[] = {8,12,15,6,9};
const int elem = 15;
const int length = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
for(int i = 0;i < length ;i++) {
    if(arr[i] != elem) {        
    //rest of your code
    }
}
```

Comment: `length` and `i` should be `Container::size_type`; the positive range of an `int` is not going to be wide enough, so using it creates potential for bugs and (if you don't often have containers with billions of elements) is just sloppy style anyway.

Answer (score 3):

one of the ways to do that it by using array index

```js
int my_idx = 2;    
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){    
 if(i == my_idx)    
    continue;    
 compare(arr[i],arr[my_idx]);    
}
```

Comment: what does compare( , ); function do?

Comment: @blank_mind, I'm pretty sure ahmed_kamal1432 is using compare() as a placeholder. You would replace that with whatever comparison you are trying to do.

Comment: as @KyleA said it's just your function to perform comparing.
I made it general to put there what you want to compare about

Comment: `length` and `i` should be `Container::size_type`; the positive range of an `int` is not going to be wide enough, so using it creates potential for bugs and (if you don't often have containers with billions of elements) is just sloppy style anyway.